# What are the differences betweeen post-apocalyptic and anarchical or dystopic?

Tags: reference-request, political-philosophy, society

When I get into the definitions for fictions like novels and movies, I've became a bit confused. For example, there are some **post-apocalyptic** fictions and when there is an authority in that fiction it seems like a **dystopic** system; vice versa it is not easy to differ the fiction from **anarchy**.

In short, **what are the apparent features** to define a system, fiction, novel or a movie as a **post-apocalyptic, dystopic and anarchical**? Are they related to social, administrative or ethic issues? Should they depend on age and time?

I'm not asking the difference between dystopia and anarchy; my subject is the difference between **post-apocalypse** and **these two**. Thanks already.

Comment: You're question is clearly about definitions for literary terms in a reference manner. I'm not seeing the philosophical question...

Comment: Do not anarchy and distopia contain philosophical approaches?? Are not some fictions and social-governal systems build on a philosophical base? OK, I would not try to appreciate the topic academically. But I don't understand why these kind of fictions could not be discussed in such manner. If so, could you please explain why it is not a philosophical question or help me to handle the topic as a philosophical question. Thank you :)

Comment: If you have a specific question about a philosophical system, then it would be philosophical. Right now, you are asking us to help you parse the definitions of literary terms.

Comment: Ok, I thought this comparative review would contain a philosophical approach. Anyway; if you say so, I'll close the question. Thanks.

Comment: Ask on English or Writers or something.  Or, in brief: post-apocalypse means "after an apocalypse".  It's not a form of government.  You could have a post-apocalyptic utopia, I suppose, though usually people imagine things being pretty messed up.

Comment: *Post-apocalyptic*: After the apocalypse, more generally, after a severe global crisis.  *Anarchy*: Without government.  *Dystopia*: A fictional place where things are horrible, the term was created as an antonym to *Utopia*, a fictional place where things are perfect.  The usual hypothesized connection is that after the apocalyptic crisis, the government collapses, leading to a dystopia.  I suppose you could tease out a philosophical question about whether there's something inevitable about that line of causality.

Answer (score 0):

"Post-apocalyptic" is just a definition of a situation occurs after apocalypse and it would be anything; utopia, distopia, anarchy, capitalism, a re-ancient age etc. Sorry for my confusion and thanks for help.